# self join with aggregate function

Tags: sql

following is my table and  sample data

```
user_id |   session_id  |   time_stamp  |   source  |   medium  |   new_source  |   new_medium

1       |   1           |   2017-01-01  |   google  |   search
1       |   2           |   2017-01-02  |   google  |   search
1       |   3           |   2017-01-03  |   direct  |   none



2       |   1           |   2017-03-11  |   google  |   search
2       |   2           |   2017-04-21  |   direct  |   none
2       |   3           |   2017-04-22  |   google  |   search
```

I want to update the new source and new medium column for each users when it meets conditions `when the user has a direct source for last|max time stamp. the new source and new medium value must be last non direct source & medium. following is expected result

```
user_id |   session_id  |   time_stamp  |   source  |   medium  | new_source    |   new_medium

1       |   1           |   2017-01-01  |   google  |   search
1       |   2           |   2017-01-02  |   google  |   search
1       |   3           |   2017-01-03  |   direct  |   none    |google     |   search



2       |   1           |   2017-03-11  |   google  |   search
2       |   2           |   2017-04-21  |   direct  |   none
2       |   3           |   2017-04-22  |   google  |   search
```

The query I tried (not working)

```
SELECT a.domain_userid,
   a.session_id,
   a.source,
   a.medium,
   b.source AS new_source,
   b.medium AS new_medium
FROM table a
  LEFT JOIN table b ON a.domain_userid = b.domain_userid
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT domain_userid,
           MAX(time_stamp) as time_stamp
    FROM table
    WHERE source != 'direct'
    GROUP BY domain_userid) AS c ON b.time_stamp = c.time_stamp and 
c.user_id=b.user_id
WHERE a.source = 'direct'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Note : join the same table and take the last none direct value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use window functions.  If there are never two "direct"s in a row, then the easiest way uses `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by user_id order by time_stamp desc) = 1 and
                  source = 'direct'
             then lag(source) over (partition by user_id order by times_stamp)
             else source
        end) as new_source,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by user_id order by time_stamp desc) = 1 and
                  source = 'direct'
             then lag(medium) over (partition by user_id order by times_stamp)
             else medium
        end) as new_medium
from t.*;
```

Comment: partitioning twice is not costly?

Comment: @pramodniralakeri . . . Compared to what?

Comment: compared to self join with aggregate or something like that? correct me if I'm thinking/talking wrong

Comment: @pramodniralakeri . . . Compared to those operations, I wouldn't worry about it.  Maybe a little faster.  Maybe a little slower.

Comment: will try your solution, get back to you

Comment: gordon, can you please elaborate/explain query little? please